# How to use Python to effectively parse a frequently updated json file?

Tags: python, json, parsing, optimization

I need to use Python to parse a json file that that has this format:

```
{
    "seldom_changed_key_0": "frequently_changed_value_0",
    "seldom_changed_key_1": "frequently_changed_value_1",
    "seldom_changed_key_2": "frequently_changed_value_2",
    "seldom_changed_key_3": "frequently_changed_value_3",
    ....
    "seldom_changed_key_n": "frequently_changed_value_n",
}
```

and this json file is huge in size(greater than 100M bytes)

As the format indicates, the content might change frequently but the format(or structure) itself seldom changes.

Each time this json file is updated, I have to re-parse it from scratch.

Do we have any optimization method that can reduce the parse time?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How about directly parsing the lines (or a line of interest), using `split`, `strip`, etc.? It might be less robust, but perhaps it might be faster (not so sure!).

Comment: See: https://simdjson.org . Besides this, if you want a 100 MB file to be loaded frequently, then you certainly need to use a binary file (possibly compressed with something like zstd). Json is a inherently inefficient data format (since it is a text format that require slow parsing). Parsing such file on a basic HDD (<100 MiB/s) or on embedded devices for example is not reasonable. Binary data formats succeed to achieve the maximum storage device throughput and are a bit more compact. If the modification are very small (eg. <5%) then you certainly need a delta-format.